# Flatten a Seq of Maps to Map using Type polymorphism in Scala, Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, generics

I have the following function that flattens a sequence of maps of string to double. How can I make type string to double generic?

```
val flattenSeqOfMaps = udf { values: Seq[Map[String, Double]] => values.flatten.toMap }
flattenSeqOfMaps: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),true))))
```

I need something like,

```
val flattenSeqOfMaps[S,D] = udf { values: Seq[Map[S, D]] => values.flatten.toMap }
```

Thanks.

Edit 1:
I'm using spark 2.3. I am aware of higher order functions in spark 2.4

Edit 2: I got a bit closer. What do I need in place of `f _` in `val flattenSeqOfMaps = udf { f _}`. Please compare `joinMap` type signature and `flattenSeqOfMaps` type signature below

```
scala> val joinMap = udf { values: Seq[Map[String, Double]] => values.flatten.toMap }
joinMap: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),true))))

scala> def f[S,D](values: Seq[Map[S, D]]): Map[S,D] = { values.flatten.toMap}
f: [S, D](values: Seq[Map[S,D]])Map[S,D]

scala> val flattenSeqOfMaps = udf { f _}
flattenSeqOfMaps: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,MapType(NullType,NullType,true),Some(List(ArrayType(MapType(NullType,NullType,true),true))))
```

Edit 3: the following code worked for me.

```
scala> val flattenSeqOfMaps = udf { f[String,Double] _}
flattenSeqOfMaps: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),true))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me.

```
scala> def f[S,D](values: Seq[Map[S, D]]): Map[S,D] = { values.flatten.toMap}
f: [S, D](values: Seq[Map[S,D]])Map[S,D]

scala> val flattenSeqOfMaps = udf { f[String,Double] _}
flattenSeqOfMaps: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),Some(List(ArrayType(MapType(StringType,DoubleType,false),true))))
```

Answer (score 2):

While you could define your function as

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

def flattenSeqOfMaps[S : TypeTag, D: TypeTag] = udf { 
  values: Seq[Map[S, D]] => values.flatten.toMap
}
```

and then use specific instances:

```
val df = Seq(Seq(Map("a" -> 1), Map("b" -> 1))).toDF("val")

val flattenSeqOfMapsStringInt = flattenSeqOfMaps[String, Int]

df.select($"val", flattenSeqOfMapsStringInt($"val") as "val").show
```

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                 val|             val|
+--------------------+----------------+
|[[a -> 1], [b -> 1]]|[a -> 1, b -> 1]|
+--------------------+----------------|
```

it is also possible to use built-in functions, without any need for explicit generics:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{expr, flatten, map_from_arrays}

def flattenSeqOfMaps_(col: String) = {
  val keys = flatten(expr(s"transform(`$col`, x -> map_keys(x))"))
  val values = flatten(expr(s"transform(`$col`, x -> map_values(x))"))
  map_from_arrays(keys, values)
}

df.select($"val", flattenSeqOfMaps_("val") as "val").show
```

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                 val|             val|
+--------------------+----------------+
|[[a -> 1], [b -> 1]]|[a -> 1, b -> 1]|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: My bad. I missed mentioning spark 2.3 version. Editing the question.